# How to create a mask in numpy conditioned on index?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, mask

```
N = 5
mask = np.zeros((N, N, N))
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        for k in range(N):
            if j==k and i!=j:
                mask[i,j,k] = 1
```

Currently I am doing it as the code shown above, i feel there must be a more efficient and pythonic way to achieve this goal

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
import numpy as np
N = 5
i, j, k = np.ogrid[:N, :N, :N]
mask = (j == k) & (i != j)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following way:

```
tiled = np.tile(np.identity(N),(N,1))
for i in range(N):
    tiled[i*N+i,i] = 0
mask = np.reshape(tiled,(N,N,N))
```

Here, you first create 2d array, insert zeros vertically, and then reshape it into 3d array. Code executes faster than original.

Original: `13.5 µs ± 305 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`

New: `10.2 µs ± 396 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)`